# Remove multiple duplicate git commits

Tags: git, github, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

Having run commands to change my author name on my repo I am now left with almost every single commit existing with both old and new author names.

How do I remove all the duplicate commits so that only one version of everything exists using only one author name?

[image: WTF?!]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have used `git filter-branch`, the original commits are available from, e.g., `refs/original/refs/heads/master`. The rewritten ones are under `refs/heads/master` aka `master`. (Insert other branch names if you have them.)

If you clone the repository into a new directory, you should receive only `master`, i.e., the rewritten commits.

You can also delete the original commits using

```
git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/master
```

Comment: That is what I did, but sadly your command to delete the original commits doesn't do anything. When I re-clone in to a new directory I do only get the master branch, but with it come all the duplicated commits

Comment: Did you check whether `refs/original/refs/heads/master` really exists or did you just trust random stuff written on the 'net ;-)?

Comment: It does exist yeah

Comment: Then delete it. The command is as in the answer. Be sure to type the correct name. Use `git show-ref` to see it.

Comment: Still no joy. Seems to be well and truly buggered

Comment: Then I must assume that your history is more complicated than your small screenshot and terse description led me to think. It may help if you show the commands with which you arrived at the duplicated commits.